# How to get notified when a StorageFile was changed through OneDrive?

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, onedrive, storagefile

I have a basic UWP Windows 10 app (running on a PC) that declares a custom file format. The user can open and edit documents of that format (much like opening a .docx file in Word Mobile, for example).

My question is this: Let's say the user opens a document from OneDrive with my app and the document is modified on another device. How can my app get notified of the change to reload the document?

Bonus question :) What if there is a conflict when the file was modified locally and on another device at the same time?

Internally I use a `StorageFile` that I obtained from a `FileOpenPicker` to read the document.

I looked into `StorageFolder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(...)`, but I can't get a reference to the StorageFile's parent folder, because my app only has permission to read the file itself, not access the parent folder.

I could periodically poll the file's modification date, but that seems far from ideal...

Answer (score 1):

I think that it could be possible with OneDrive API and [webhooks](https://dev.onedrive.com/webhooks/webhooks.htm)
Unfortunately I can't find any example for UWP (there is only [one for ASP.NET](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-webhooks-aspnet) available)

You can also try to do it with [ContentsChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.search.storagefolderqueryresult.contentschanged.aspx) event

```
 auto query = folder.CreateFileQuery();
 query.ContentsChanged += queryContentsChanged;
```

.......

```
void queryContentsChanged(IStorageQueryResultBase sender, object args) 
{
    // check what was changed 
}
```

You can find some information here: [File system change notifications in WinRT](http://lunarfrog.com/blog/filesystem-change-notifications)

That should work with OneDrive also, because of smart files concept. As taken from this article: [Working with files across the local PC and SkyDrive](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/12/06/working-with-files-across-the-local-pc-and-skydrive/)

> As a developer, think of SkyDrive files as “just files” – they use the same StorageFile interface as every other file on the system and can be manipulated in much the same way.
>
> A smart file is a file that appears on the system like a regular file but only contains metadata and thumbnails, not full file contents. The contents for the file are located on SkyDrive and can be downloaded as needed.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the plain UWP API? Ideally this should work for other providers such as Dropbox and iCloud Drive as well... Pretty much any case where the file could be changed outside of the app while it is open.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I looked into file queries before, but ran into the problem that my app does not have permission to access the parent folder. I get the StorageFile instance from a FileOpenPicker. Calling GetParentAsync() on that always returns null. Is there another way?

Comment: You can let user first select folder and only then to select file (from custom control with file names inside). In this case you will be have permissions to access folder and files inside this folder

Comment: That would probably work, but from a UX point of view it seems to be very cumbersome. I'm still hoping to discover a better way as this seems to be such a common use case...